# R Shiny get click information from scatterD3

Tags: r, shiny

I have a scatterd3 (package scatterd3) plot in a shiny app and I can't figure out how to pass information after clicking a plotted point back to shiny though. This website seems to explain it but I just can't get it:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterD3/vignettes/introduction.html#javascript-callback-on-clicking-point

```
scatterD3(data = mtcars, x = wt, y = mpg,
  click_callback = "function(id, index) {
  if(id && typeof(Shiny) != 'undefined') {
      Shiny.onInputChange(id + '_selected', index);
  }
}")
```

Do you know where the information on click is stored? I assumed I could call it in shiny gui with something like this:

```
verbatimTextOutput("scatterPlot$index")
```

Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `click_callback` JavaScript function is called with two arguments : the plot unique id, and the clicked point index. By using `Shiny.onInputChange`, you can bind a Shiny `input` slot to a value and get back the data.

For example, with the following `click_callback` function :

```
scatterD3(data = mtcars, x = wt, y = mpg,
  click_callback = "function(id, index) {
  if(id && typeof(Shiny) != 'undefined') {
      Shiny.onInputChange('selected_point', index);
  }
}")
```

You should be able to do something like :

```
verbatimTextOutput(paste("Index of clicked point : ", input$selected_point))
```

This is quite a recent feature in `scatterD3`, so in case of bug or missing feature, don't hesitate to [open an issue on Github](https://github.com/juba/scatterD3/issues).

Comment: Thanks, that got me sorted, I'll add some details to a reply to my question

Answer (score 1):

juba's answer helped a lot, see above.
I wanted to update a numericInput field, so went about it like this in my server:

```
observe({
  click_index <- input$selected_point
  updateNumericInput(session, "numeric1", value=click_index)
})
```

Where my numericInput in my gui was:

```
numericInput("numeric1", "Clicked point index :", value=0)
```